# Genymotion Android emulator - adb access?

Tags: android, adb, virtualbox, emulation, genymotion

I downloaded Genymotion Android emulators for Oracle VirtualBox (http://www.genymotion.com/) on my Windows 7 PC, created a virtual Jelly Bean with Google Apps device. How do I enable ADB access to it? In system settings/Developer options I already enabled "USB debugging", but typing "adb devices" shows empty list of connected devices. Tried adding a USB port for this VM and rebooting VM, but it does not help.

Greg

Answer (score 47, accepted):

We need to connect with IP address to the emulator, so look for the IP address of the running emulator (it's shown in the emulator title bar) and use something like:

> adb connect 192.168.56.102:5555

Afterward `adb` works normally. You may also find out the IP address of a running emulator by starting "Genymotion Shell" and typing 'devices list'

I also find out that occasionally I have to do the above when the emulator is running for a longer time and somehow ADB disconnects from it.

Greg

Comment: Genymotion now shows IP address in window title, and you should use port 5555.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, solved my problem. I suggest you to include what @hunyadym said, because I've spent a few minutes searching for genymotion's IP before reading it :p

Comment: Why from the prompt it says `adb is not recognized as an internal or external command`?

Comment: @NineCattoRules you need to navigate to <sdk location>/platform-tools/ and then do adb commands

Comment: @hunyadym actually it shows for me and I could fix my problem using this hint!

Comment: I'm wondering, if the answer of your question is this post (_as you wrote "OK, nevermind, found the answer here."_) why you marked @eyal-lezmy's answer as correct answer?

Answer (score 39):

If you launch the VM with the the launchpad (genymotion binary where you download the VMs) and you set the Android SDK path into the application parameters the connection is automatic and you don't need to run `adb connect`

You can find the information in the [Genymotion Docs](https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/3.0/02_Application/021_Configuring_Genymotion.html#adb).

Comment: thank you for this information. I think I lunched it that way the first time, and it did not work. Maybe I don't remember correctly though, or they fixed something since then. I'll upvote your answer when I'm back at my computer and test it.

Comment: thank you again, looks like it works the way you say. Up-voted your answer now. I also see that VM works differently when started from this console, there are extra buttons on the side etc. Strangely, it also often with "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped", while I did not see these errors when starting Oracle VM. Must investigate this some more.

Comment: Actually the genymotion player is used to add functionalities. You can also manage other parameters like gps, battery, and rotation. About the force close, you should add a ticket on the support page on the website. Don't forget to precise your whole config. https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/support/#

Comment: The FC was happening on an Android VM which I was starting directly from VirtualBox. Maybe the VM was damaged in the process. I deleted it now and re-created, starting only from Genymotion player, seems OK now. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Run Genymotion (not the emulator the program itself) -> settings -> ADB -> Find your path

Answer (score 8):

Simply do this, with genymotion device running you can open Virtual Box , and see that there is a VM for you device , then go to network Settings of the VM, NAT and do port forwarding of local 5555 to remote 5555 
screen attached[Virtual Box Nat Network Port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfjGS.png)

Comment: this answer work for me, none of above worked :) thanks for answer

Comment: Yes.. it helped me finally on Mac !

Answer (score 6):

My working solution is:

```sh
cd /opt/genymobile/genymotion/tools
./adb shell
```

You have to use its own **adb** tool.

Answer (score 3):

Connect didn't work for me, The problem was that Genymotion uses its own dk-tools and you need to change it to custom SDK tools.

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26630862/4154438

Answer (score 2):

Just Go To the Genymotion Installation Directory  and then in folder tools you will see adb.exe there open command prompt here and run adb commands

Answer (score 1):

I know it's way too late to answer this question, but I'll just post the solution that worked for me, in case someone runs into trouble again in the future.

I tried using genymotion's own adb tools and the original Android SDK ones, and even purging and reinstalling adb from my system, but nothing worked. I kept getting the error:
 `adb server is out of date. killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
*failed to start daemon*
error:`


So I tried `adb connect [ip]` as suggested here, but I didn't work either, the same error came up.

What finally worked for me was downloading [ADT](http://tools.android.com/download), and running adb directly from the downloaded folder, instead of the system-wide command. So `adb devices` will give me the error above, but `/yourdownloadpath/adb devices` works just fine for me.
 
Hope it helped.

Answer (score -1):

You can get IP **Genymotion Virtual Device Manager**,then use the command like this

```
adb connect your ip
```

Comment: What does this answer add? You just repeat fractions of what others have said.