# How to use adb with genymotion on mac?

Tags: android, macos, cordova, genymotion

I am using cordova to build apps for android, on Mac OS X 10.9.4.

I am using genymotion to create virtual devices.

Yesterday I was able to get 'cordova run android' to get my apps to run on a genymotion virtual device.

Today, I thought I repeated the steps I took yesterday, but I can't get it to work.

I start the adb server (with genymotion not running) with

```
adb start-server
```

adb server starts up fine:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

I can see it's there

```
lsof -i tcp:5037
adb     19131 bw    7u  IPv4 0x3c0bc54e449e35f5      0t0  TCP localhost:5037 (LISTEN)
```

There's no devices attached

```
adb devices
```

So far so good

Now when I start up genymotion, and start a virtual device, my adb seems to have been killed and cannot start because the virtual device has apparently killed it and started its own adb instance

```
unknown-6c-40-08-9b-25-2c:todo bw$ adb devices
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:
```

This now gives me no way to add the device to adb so that I can access it by doing

```
cordova run android
```

This command now fails, because it can't find a running device.

I tried running adb start-server as root, so that genymotion couldn't kill it, but then the genymotion virtual device wouldn't start up.

What gives? Grateful for any ideas.. Thanks!

Comment: what IDE are you using, if any?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it's not entirely satisfactory, but I have got it to work.

When I change the settings in genymotion under the settings->adb tab to reference my android sdk rather than the built-in genymotion android tools, everything works fine. That's great, but I don't understand how it can have been working yesterday before I changed that setting. Oh well. Hopefully this will help someone.

[image]

Comment: Where exactly you find "settings in genymotion under the adb tab" ?

Comment: When I open GenyMotion 2.3.0, there is an icon with 'Settings' under it. If I click on that, there is a set of tabs, one of which is called 'ADB'. Have updated my answer for clarity.