# ADB with Genymotion - error

Tags: android, adb

After reading many threads ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630398/how-to-use-adb-with-genymotion-on-mac), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431972/android-studio-lollipop-adb-genymotion-issues-devices-wont-show-up-adb), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757191/adb-and-genymotion-error-adb-server-is-out-of-date-killing-cannot-bind-tc)) and trying many solutions in SO regarding similar error, I still am unable to find a solution for this error.

```
$ adb devices

List of devices attached
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037': Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: 
error:
```

I have Genymotion 2.7.2, have provided explicit sdk path under Genymotion -> adb -> Android SDK, using adb version 1.0.32.

Comment: Are you on the latest version of the `platform-tools` ? Did you try to `ALT + CTRL + DELETE` and end the `adb.exe` process tree ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29524143/1778421

Answer (score -1):

open task manager and find adb.exe and kill it, then restart your eclipse and 
type adb `kill-server` in your cmd (if you are using windows)
for other OS type `killall adb`