# React Native does not install app on genymotion

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

I am using genymotion in windows and I want to use react native to develop an application. but here is the thing:

I can connect my phone to PC and this works fine, but when I want to use genymotion, when I run `react-native run-android` it compiles and build the project successfully but there is no installation on genymotion emulator. adb recognizes my emulator and this is not the problem. only there is no installation and no app preview on emulator.

Comment: Is genymotion connected to the computer correctly?

Comment: How should it be connected? I installed it and then added a new device and the I ran it.

Comment: have a look to this question, it solved my problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530181/genymotion-android-emulator-adb-access?rq=1

Comment: @ahmedwahba I actually switched to Android Studio